# Android: How to apply .psd (Photoshop Template) in android App

Tags: android, templates, user-interface, photoshop, psd

When I am searching for Android Template so I got lot of URLs Like:

`Free Android GUI PSD`http://ntt.cc/2010/08/03/6-free-android-gui-psd-templates-for-designers.html
   `Stencils Template`http://graffletopia.com/stencils/498

On lots of link I found .psd file (Layer Photoshop) but how can I use these files into Android Development.

I dont have Idea to improve GUI Look & Feel of my Android Application.

If someone can give sample code..

Comment: Some more Link of .psd but how to use these for improving gui of android apps? `Firework Template`<http://unitid.nl/2009/11/fireworks-template-for-android/> `Google Android GUI`<http://chrisbrummel.com/google-android-gui-psd>

Comment: This section of the Android Developer Guide will help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: It would be great if you could use templates to directly change them to xml resources, but I don't think it's possible. And even if there was such a tool it would be just like generating html with photoshop - it's just rubbish. These templates are for designing purposes, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

if you can't slicing then you should hire someone who will slice for you and you will be able to use the design.